# Haskell - Trying to generate a list (size m) of strings (size n)

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to define a function that takes two integer values m and n. It returns a value that can be displayed as a rectangle.

```
e.g. rectangle 3 4
****
****
****
```

In my code, I'm getting a syntax error saying I have the wrong type [Char], but I'm not using a char anywhere.

The code:

```
rectangle :: Int -> Int -> [String]
rectangle m n = generateRectangle m n []

generateRectangle :: Int -> Int -> [String] -> [String]
generateRectangle m n currentRectangle =
    if length currentRectangle < n then
        generateRectangle m n (addRow m ""):currentRectangle
    else
        currentRectangle

addRow :: Int -> String -> String
addRow size currentRow =
    if length currentRow < size then
        addRow size currentRow++"*"
    else
        currentRow
```

The error:

```
    ERROR file:test.hs:8 - Type error in application
*** Expression     : generateRectangle m n (addRow m "")
*** Term           : addRow m ""
*** Type           : [Char]
*** Does not match : [String]
```

Comment: `String` is just an alias for `[Char]`, and when you're using an abandonware compiler like Hugs it likely won't give you the best error messages.  I strongly advocate for using GHC over Hugs since it's still maintained.

Comment: @bheklilr I'll try it out, thanks for the suggestion. I'm only using this because it's what our lecturer has suggested everyone to use.

Comment: Make sure you check out ghci, which is GHC's interactive component that's much like the Hugs prompt (doesn't behave entirely the same though so do read up on it). Just bear in mind if your lecturer wants code submitted and you've written it to work in GHC it might not run in Hugs if you accidentally used something Hugs doesn't support, so do check before you submit your coursework.

Comment: @MatthewWalton Will do!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `addRow` returns a `String`, which is a `[Char]`. However, your `generateRectangle` expects a `[String]`, which is a `[[Char]]`:

```
    generateRectangle m n (addRow m "") : currentRectangle
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                          this is a String, not a [String]
```

That's the same as

```
    (generateRectangle m n (addRow m "")) : currentRectangle
```

and the types don't match.

You probably meant this instead:

```
    generateRectangle m n ((addRow m "") : currentRectangle)
```

Remember, function application has the highest precedence.

---

That being said, try to write a function

```
repeatNTimes :: Int -> a -> [a]
```

instead. Then, you can write `rectangle` using that function two times:

```
rectangle n m = repeatNTimes ??? (repeatNTimes ??? ???)
```

Maybe you even know a function that acts like `repeatNTimes`, but try to figure it out on your own first.

Comment: Thank you! That got rid of the syntax error. I'll definitely look into your suggestions.

Comment: @Toby Take care! Your error is not a syntax one. It's a type error. Which means that your syntax was fine, but your types weren't. For example, `(2 :: Double) + (3 :: Int)` is fine syntax-wise, but `(+)` only works if both arguments use the same type wheras `+ 2 3` is a syntax error. Try both in your interpreter. Nitpicky, but important.